# How to show all pages for a search result from leiningen?

Tags: leiningen

I can search for packages in leiningen in the console by executing

```
$ lein search jdbc
```

However this only returns the first page out of many. I would like to get all pages and just grep search for the stuff I want. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script of some sort that iterated through

```
lein search jdbc $i
```

, where `i` is incremented starting at 1, but the loop finishes when the answer is just "Searching over Artifact ID..."

Your script would have to be concatenating the results together to give you a string to grep from.

Ordinary answer I know...